# numpy ndarray error in lmfit when mdel is passed using sympy

Tags: numpy, sympy, lmfit

I got the following error:

> <lambdifygenerated-1>:2: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.return numpy.array((A1*exp(-1/2*(x - xc1)**2/sigma1**2), 0, 0))

Here I have just one model but this code is written for model combination in fitting by the lmfit Please kindly let me know about it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sympy
from sympy.parsing import sympy_parser
import lmfit

gauss_peak1 = sympy_parser.parse_expr('A1*exp(-(x-xc1)**2/(2*sigma1**2))')
gauss_peak2 = 0
exp_back = 0

model_list = sympy.Array((gauss_peak1, gauss_peak2, exp_back))
model = sum(model_list)
print(model)



model_list_func = sympy.lambdify(list(model_list.free_symbols), model_list)
model_func = sympy.lambdify(list(model.free_symbols), model)


np.random.seed(1)
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 40)
param_values = dict(x=x, A1=2, sigma1=1, xc1=2)
y = model_func(**param_values)
yi = model_list_func(**param_values)
yn = y + np.random.randn(y.size)*0.4

plt.plot(x, yn, 'o')
plt.plot(x, y)


lm_mod = lmfit.Model(model_func, independent_vars=('x'))
res = lm_mod.fit(data=yn, **param_values)
res.plot_fit()
plt.plot(x, y, label='true')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lmfit.Model` takes a model function that is a Python function.  It parses the function arguments and expects those to be the Parameters for the model.

I don't think using sympy-created functions will do that.   Do you need to use sympy here?  I don't see why. The usage here seems designed to make the code more complex than it needs to be.  It seems you want to make a model with a Gaussian-like peak, and a constant(?) background.    If so, why not do

```
from lmfit.Models import GaussianModel, ConstantModel

model = GaussianModel(prefix='p1_') + ConstantModel()
params = model.make_params(p1_amplitude=2, p1_center=2, p1_sigma=1, c=0)
```

That just seems way easier to me, and it is very easy to add a second Gaussian peak to that model.

But even if you have your own preferred mathematical expression, don't use that as a sympy string, use it as Python code:

```
def myfunction(x, A1, xc1, sigma1):
    return A1*exp(-(x-xc1)**2/(2*sigma1**2))
```

and then

```
from lmfit import Model
mymodel = Model(myfunction)
params = mymodel.guess(A1=2, xc1=2, sigma1=1)
```

In short: sympy is an amazing tool, but lmfit does not use it.

Comment: Sure, but this play with the sympy is provided by the lmfit (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/examples/example_sympy.html). I need to use it or build function based on my lambdified expression drived from sympy.